# A multidimensional change of variable problem

Tags: calculus, integration, change-of-variable

\begin{align}
\int\int{\exp(-k|x_1-x_2|^2)d^2x_1d^2x_2}
\end{align}

How to perform the integration of the integral above by changing the variable to the center of mass and relative coordinate,as below, 
\begin{align}
u&=(x_2+x_1)\\
v&=\frac{1}{2}(x_2-x_1)
\end{align}

Comment: What have you tried? Were you introduced to the theorem for multivariable change of basis?

Comment: Is it $d^{2}x_1d^{2}x_2$ or $dx_1dx_2$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy physicists uses the notation $d^n x_k$ to indicate integral over the $n$ coordinates of a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @NikiDiGiano I figured out that somehow integrating in center of mass frame might simplify the problem, that's why I'm trying to do so and yeah i know very basics of multivariable change of basis. Thank you @ achillehui for the clarification.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter thank you for noticing the blunder typo i made..it'll be $|x_1-x_2|^2$, i have edited the question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about the quantity
$$Q:=\int_{{\mathbb R}^2\times{\mathbb R}^2}\exp\bigl(-k|x-y|^2\bigr)\>{\rm d}(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)\ .$$
Unfortunately $Q=\infty$. In order to show this we use the transformation
$$x_1={u_1+v_1\over2},\quad y_1={v_1-u_1\over2},\quad x_2={u_2+v_2\over2},\quad y_2={v_2-u_2\over2}\ .\tag{1}$$
Then $x-y=(u_1,u_2)$, and the Jacobian of $(1)$ computes to ${1\over4}$. It follows that
$$Q={1\over4}\int_{{\mathbb R}^2\times{\mathbb R}^2}\exp\bigl(-k(u_1^2+u_2^2)\bigr)\>{\rm d}(u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2)\ .$$
Here the $u$-integral is fine, but the $v$-integral is $=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll set $x_1=x$ and $x_2=y,$ and also use the familiar notation for differentials. Then I'll call your integrand $F(x,y)$ and your equations $x=f(u,v),\,y=g(u,v).$

Calculate the Jacobian of the transformation $(u,v)\mapsto (x,y).$ This is the determinant formed by the partials of $x=f(u,v),\,y=g(u,v).$ In particular, the first row contains the partials of $x$ wrt $u,v$ in that order, and the second row something similar for $y.$ Then your integral is $$\iint F(x,y)|J(u,v)|\mathrm du \mathrm dv,$$ where $x=f(u,v),\,y=g(u,v)$ from your equations, provided $J(u,v)$ does not vanish.

By the way you didn't indicate the region of integration, so this is as far as can be said.

Comment: In the question if you see carefully it is  $d^2x_1 d^2x_2$ not $dx_1 dx_2$.

Comment: @isoura Oh. So these are second-order differentials?

Comment: if you see the discussions below the question , it might help you understanding it.